# How to get commits of linux kernel?

Tags: linux, commit

I was on slashdot and noticed that people are talking about companies that contribute code to the linux kernel. Is there a website that lists who did the most commits per kernel update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LWN](https://lwn.net/) publishes these at every kernel release; here are the stats for [2.6.38](https://lwn.net/Articles/429912/) and for [3.0](https://lwn.net/Articles/451243/).